# Modificación del voto de cierre

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Han hecho [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2898/diferencias-de-uso-entre-intellij-idea-y-eclipse) a la que he votado por cerrar y comentado por estar demasiado basada en opiniones: [**Diferencias de uso entre `IntelliJ Idea` y `Eclipse`**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2898/diferencias-de-uso-entre-intellij-idea-y-eclipse).

Pero, al mirar, me he dado cuenta que el voto emitido es erróneo, ya que he puesto como demasiado amplia, lo que claramente no es correcto.

¿Qué es preferible?

- **Retirar el voto** ya que no puedo modificarlo (aunque la pregunta merezca ser cerrada)
- **Mantenerlo** aunque sea erróneo

Answer (score 5):

Ante la duda, retira el voto. Si realmente la publicación es "mala", reunirá de todas formas los votos necesarios para su cierre.

Comment: *la hemos liao*, XD ha aparecido un nuevo voto y comentario que les pasa exactamente lo mismo que a mi...  entiendo tu postura, pero en un foro no tan activo como StackOverflow ingles, creo que un voto es importante (y mas ahora que son 2).... xD

Comment: Al final terminó cerrándose, pero es cierto, al ser en español y relativamente nuevo, ya que no llega a ni un año, un voto es importante.